# Log4j to Log4j2 conversion

Tags: xml, log4j, log4j2

I have a log4.xml file that i use for custom logging

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Console appender -->
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-4p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- File appender -->
    <appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <param name="File" value="test/logs/app.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="64MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-5p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I need to convert this to log4j2 and have come up with the following but i'm not sure if this is correct

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
    <!-- Console appender -->
    <Parameters>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    </Parameters>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-4p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n"/>
        </Console>
        <!-- File appender -->
        <RollingFile name="DAILY_LOG" fileName="test/logs/app.log"
                     filePattern="app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz"
>
            <PatternLayout pattern="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-5p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="64MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="info"/>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

    </Configuration>
```

Anyone know if i'm correct or on the right track here? It doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll this every day then you shouldn't use a file pattern with hours and minutes in it.  However, if you do want the file to have the hours and minutes in it then use the CronTriggeringPolicy instead of the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.

Comment: No i don't want a file pattern with hours and minutes I want it be be for example `app.log` for the current log, then `app.log.2016-06-13`, `app.log.2016-06-12` for days past